# Only showing the info window of second pin

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

After I add info windows to my pin array, when I click on the second pin the `infowindow` pops up over the first pin. And when I click on the first pin the second pin's `infowindow` pops up.

This is the pin array:

```
function setMarkers(map) {
// Adds markers to the map.

var image = {
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/wp-content/plugins/wp_cat_map/assets/img/home_pin.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(35, 42),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 42)
};

var shape = {
    coords: [0, 0, 35, 42],
    type: 'rect'
};

for (var i = 0; i < thePins.length; i++) {

    var pin = thePins[i];

    var contentString = pin[0];

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString,
        maxWidth: 200
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: pin[1], lng: pin[2]},
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        //shape: shape,
        title: pin[0],
        zIndex: pin[3]
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Your `localhost:8888` "Test Page" link isn't reachable by anyone else.

Comment: Sorry I know that. I forgot it was my local site. Thanks for removing.

Comment: duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: @geocodezip that question is nothing like mine! Seriously, I am asking a completely different question. The fellow from that question was asking for someone to do the work for him. I was asking why my code, which I had done myself, was not working. His code didn't even include the functions for the info windows. It didn't include and functions at all.

Comment: The code in the answer to that question solves your problem.  If it doesn't help you, it might help someone else.

Comment: I see where you are coming from, but their title did not reflect my question and if I wanted spoon feeding to get my answer then I would of looked at that question a long time ago without working on it myself. It's a bit unreasonable to expect me to of found that question when their title wasn't relevant and all they where asking was, "here is my array, do the work for me". I will look harder next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [variable hoisting](http://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/), all of those `marker` and `infowindow` references are to the *same* variable, whose declaration is basically moved up to the top of the containing function.

You either need to wrap the handler-creating in an anonymous function, or just move it to a separate, regular function.  e.g.

```
function addMarker(pin, map, image, contentString) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString,
    maxWidth: 200
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: pin[1], lng: pin[2]},
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    title: pin[0],
    zIndex: pin[3]
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < thePins.length; i++) {
  var pin = thePins[i];
  var contentString = pin[0];

  addMarker( pin, map, image, contentString);
}
```